# Loading two components from same url access - Angular2 routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am developing a single page application using Angular2. In my home page, I need two lists of objects to be displayed. For instance, the category list and the advertisements list.

When the URL is accessed, I need both the lists to display the content in the same page. I cannot populate both the lists in the same component since I need the advertisement list to be updated once the category is selected.

What I am planing to do is to create two parallel router outlets in my `app.component.html`. Those two router outlets will be handled by two different components.

```
<router-outlet name="category-list"> </router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="ad-list"> </router-outlet>
```

I looked for the ways of doing this on internet. They all have more than one router outlets as I need, but those outlets have their own urls. (The objects will be displayed once the link is clicked)

Following is one of the tutorials I followed. In that, the information of the person is displayed once the relevant button is clicked.

http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

In my case, I have no separate urls for two router outlets. But they have two separate components to manipulate the data for them.

How should I configure the routes. Can I do something like following?

```
{ path: 'home', 
  components: [
     AdsComponent, 
     CategoryComponent
  ],
  outlet: // I don't know how to configure it
}
```

Comment: you can wrap both into a component and refer that in the route

Comment: you mean to load both the lists in one component and to have a one single router outlet?

Comment: update the post with your code I will try fixing it